# How to detect and resolve polymorphic association for counter_culture gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, polymorphic-associations

I followed the [RailsCast #154 on Polymorphic Association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised) to setup a migration as follows:

```
# db/migrate/20130719120000_create_comments.rb
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :subject
      t.text :message
      t.belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true    
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :comments, [:commentable_id, :commentable_type]
  end
end
```

The model then looks like this:

```
# app/models/comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :message, :subject
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  counter_culture :commentable # This does not work, read below.
end
```

A comment can be set to multiple models, here is one example:

```
# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

This works just fine.

---

Now I also use the [gem counter_culture](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture) (as you can see in the *Comment* model) which simple counts the number of comments. It stores the count value as property of the associated model, *Product* in this case. The **integration worked before** I switched the *Comment* model to polymorphism.

When I change `counter_culture :commentable` to `counter_culture :product` I end up with the following error message:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `product' for #<Comment:0x0000000531cdb0>
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/activemodel-3.2.13/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/counter_culture-0.1.12/lib/counter_culture.rb:301:in `foreign_key_value'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/counter_culture-0.1.12/lib/counter_culture.rb:243:in `change_counter_cache'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/counter_culture-0.1.12/lib/counter_culture.rb:196:in `block (2 levels) in _update_counts_after_create'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/counter_culture-0.1.12/lib/counter_culture.rb:194:in `each'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/counter_culture-0.1.12/lib/counter_culture.rb:194:in `block in _update_counts_after_create'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/counter_culture-0.1.12/lib/counter_culture.rb:186:in `call'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/counter_culture-0.1.12/lib/counter_culture.rb:186:in `_wrap_in_counter_culture_active'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/counter_culture-0.1.12/lib/counter_culture.rb:193:in `_update_counts_after_create'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2202164684578441182__create__891150410440608527__callbacks'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_create_callbacks'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:268:in `create'
    from /home/jjd/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@demoapp/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:348:in `create_or_update'
```

This basically refers to `_update_counts_after_create` in [line 192](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture/blob/master/lib/counter_culture.rb#L192).

```
# Source: https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture/blob/master/lib/counter_culture.rb#L192
# called by after_create callback
def _update_counts_after_create
  _wrap_in_counter_culture_active do
    self.class.after_commit_counter_cache.each do |hash|
      # increment counter cache
      change_counter_cache(hash.merge(:increment => true))
    end
  end
end
```

When I inspect the `hash` while `counter_culture :commentable` is set I can see that the `:relation` has to been resolved to the *Product* model.

```
{:relation=>[:commentable], :counter_cache_name=>"comments_count", :column_names=>nil, :foreign_key_values=>nil}
```

I assume this should be done in [line 29](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture/blob/master/lib/counter_culture.rb#L29) where the relation is assigned.

```
:relation => relation.is_a?(Enumerable) ? relation : [relation],
```

How can I test if `relation` is a polymorphic association to resolve the *Product* model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there is actually a [discussion about polymorphism support](https://github.com/magnusvk/counter_culture/issues/4) going on and that there is [fork by Dan Maglasang (last updated January 16, 2013, branched off at v.0.1.8)](https://github.com/dorilla/counter_culture). I checked it out and it worked out of the box for me.
I asked the author to rebase his branch to update the project.